# Generation query when the ManyToMany relationship is used by Spring Data project

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

I've the following entities mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "service_personnel"
            , joinColumns = { @JoinColumn }
            , inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn }
    )
    private Set<Personnel> personnel = new HashSet<>();
//geters, setters, other
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Personnel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "personnel")
    private Set<Service> service = new HashSet<>();
```

ServiceRepository interface is looked:

```
    public interface ServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Service, Long> {

        @Query("SELECT b FROM Service b INNER JOIN b.personnel c WHERE c IN (:personnel)")
        public List<Service> findByPersonnel(@Param("personnel") Collection<Personnel> personnel);

        public List<Service> findById(Long id);
```

Please fix me if I'm wrong in the query itself or name method(findById). When I run test Postman return " Expected ':' instead of 't' " but browser return multiple the same JSONs without end bracket.

I try also:

```
public List<Service> findByPersonnel_Id(Long id);
```

but effect is the same.

Comment: Postman, and a browser, allow sending HTTP requests. The code you posted has nothing to do with HTTP requests: it's a JPA entity and a repository allowing to query for entities in a database. What is the query you send, what is the actual response you get what is the response you expect, and what is the **relevant** code handling this HTTP request and sending back the HTTP response?

Comment: You should have a StackOverflowError or something in your logs: you're trying to serialize to JSON a list of services. Each of these service has a set of personnels that need to be serialized. Each of these personnel has a list of services that need to be serialized. And each of these services have a set of personnel that need to be serialized. Etc. etc. So ad the necessary annotations to ignore fields that shouldn't be serialized. or use DTOs without that circular association.